# erroe with carrierwave for showing file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, carrierwave, erb

I have installed gem and followed all the instructions.

```
rails g uploader File

rails g migration add_file_to_users file:string
```

After that I uploaded the image as file and it succeeded.

Although it's uploaded, when I go to show it its not working.

My code in `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= image_tag @user.file_url if @user.file? %>
```

I tried adding:

```
<%= @user.file.inspect %>
```

but it's not showing me the url for image I uploaded.

Thank you.

Comment: what you get when you try <%= @user.file.inspect %> this?

Comment: Since you ran a migration and added the file - did you add it to the strong params of user?

Comment: It may not be the problem, but as a general comment - don't use `File` as your class name, that's already a pretty important class! Does the `User` show data in the file column via console? Can you see the file on disk?